# How to change resolution without compromising video quality using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, transcoding

I'm trying to develop a simple video transcoding system. When you upload a video, After extracting the video and audio separately, I want to encode them at 360, 720, and 1080p resolutions respectively and then merge them to create three final mp4 files. At this time, I have two questions.

1. Is there a big difference between encoding the video and audio separately in the original video file and encoding the original video file as is? In a related book, it is said that a system is created by separating video and audio, and I am curious as to why.
2. I want to change the resolution without compromising the original image quality. At this time, the resolution of the uploaded file can be known at the time of upload. As a test, I created files according to each resolution, and found that the image quality was damaged. If I want to change only the resolution while keeping the original image quality, I would like to know how to adjust each ffmpeg option. We plan to change it to 360, 720, and 1080p.
3. Lastly, are there appropriate settings for the three resolutions (360, 720, 1080) that I am trying to convert to ffmpeg?